# Compact Hausdorff space, embeddings and homeomorphisms.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I'm really struggling trying to comprehend some aspects of embeddings. In particular, the problem I'm having is the relation between embeddings and homeomorphisms.

Let $C$ be a compact Hausdorff space with the property that for all $c \in C$, we can find a neigborhood (open) that can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ for some k. **Does this mean that all open neigborhoods are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{k}$?** Can I call this space $C$ as a $k$-manifold?

I want to prove that $C$ in fact can be embedded in some $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ by using the embedding theorem for compact manifolds, but to use it it I have to be able to show that C is in fact a manifold, thats why I want to see if the neigborhoods are all homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{k}$.

Any comments, proofs, resources are welcome.

Comment: No, let C be any finite set with discrete topology. You need to explicitly require the open neighborhood is isomorphic to the open unit ball in R^k, and to be a manifold the transition maps need to be continuous.

Comment: Does k depend on the point $c\in C$ chosen?

Comment: I think not, I mean for all $c \in C$ there exist a fixed k such that all open neigborhoods, lets call them $U_{c}$, can be embedded in $R^{k}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Any compact $C  \subset \mathbb R^k$ has the property that each $c \in C$ has an open neigborhood in $C$ that can be embedded in $\mathbb R^k$. Actually we may take any open neigborhood $U$ of $c$ in $C$ since $U \subset \mathbb R^k$.

I think you mean that each $c \in C$ has an open neighborhood which can embedded as an *open subset* of $\mathbb R^k$. Then in fact $C$ is a $k$-manifold. But of course you cannot expect that that all open neigborhoods are homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^k$. There are such "nice" neighborhoods, but also other neigborhoods (just remove a compact subset from a nice neighborhood).

**Update on request:**

Let $C$ be a compact space such that for each $c \in C$ there exists  an open neighborhood $U_c \subset C$ and an embedding $\phi_c : U_c \to \mathbb R^{k(c)}$ for some $k(c)$. We shall construct an embedding $h : C \to \mathbb R^N$ for a sufficiently large $N$. Since $C$ is compact Hausdorff, hence normal, we find open  $V_c \subset C$ such that $c \in V_c \subset \overline {V_c} \subset U_c$ and a continuous Urysohn-function $u_c : C \to [0,1]$  such that $u_c(c) = 1$ and $u_c(x) = 0$ for $x \in C \setminus V_c$. Define
$$g_c : C \to \mathbb R^{k(c)} \times \mathbb R = \mathbb R^{k(c)+1} , g_c(x) = \begin{cases} (u_c(x) h_c(x), u_c(x) )& x \in \overline {V_c} \\ (0, u_c(x)) = (0,0) & x \in C \setminus V_c \end{cases}$$
Both parts of the definition yield continuous functions on the closed subsets $\overline {V_c}$ and $C \setminus V_c$ of $C$, respectively. On $\overline {V_c} \cap (C \setminus V_c) = \operatorname{bd} V_c$ both parts agree, therefore $g_c$ is continuous.

Let $W_c = u_c^{-1}((0,1])$. This is an open subset of $C$ such that $c \in W_c \subset V_c$.

Claim: If $g_c(x) = g_c(y)$ and $x \in W_c$, then $x = y$.

Proof. $g_c(x) = g_c(y)$ implies $u_x(x) = u_x(y)$. For $x \in W_c$ we have $u_c(x) > 0$, thus also $u_c(y) > 0$ which shows $y \in W_c$. Hence $x,y \in W_c \subset V_c$ and thus $u_c(x) h_c(x) = u_c(y) h_c(y)$. Since $u_c(x) = u_c(y) > 0$, we conclude that $h_c(x) = h_c(y)$ and therefore $x = y$.

Since $C$ is compact, finitely many $W_{c_i}$ cover $C$. Define
$$h : C \to \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb R^{k(c_i)+1} = \mathbb R^N, h(x) = (g_{c_1}(x), \ldots, g_{c_n}(x)) .$$

We shall check that $h$ is injective; thus it is an embedding because $C$ is compact. So let $x, y \in C$ such that $h(x) = h(y)$. We have $x \in W_{c_i}$ for some $i$, thus $g_{c_i}(x) = g_{c_i}(y)$ with $x \in W_{c_i}$. Our above claim shows that $x = y$.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer! But then, do you have any idea of how to prove that C in fact can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ knowing that for all $c \in C$, there is a open neigborhood $U_{c}$ can be embedded in some $\mathbb{R}^{j}$?

Answer (score 1):

If $C$ is compact then:

- $C$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$ for any $k$ because this last space is not compact (unless $C$ is a point and $k=0$, which we will exclude because it is not interesting)
- $C$ is itself an open neighbourhood of any of its point

Hence, "all open neighbourhoods in $C$ are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k$" is always a false statement unless $C$ is a point.

Comment: @PaulFrost I don't get your point